# Text View is not displayed on the scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a view controller names as TeamDetailsViewController.
I added scroll view to the view controller programmatically and added UITextview as the subview of the scroll view. But Text View is not showing up for an unknown reason. Please help. Here is my code

```
class TeamDetailsController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false

        setupViews()
    }

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        sv.backgroundColor = .blue

        sv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing(rawValue: UIViewAutoresizing.RawValue(UInt8(UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth.rawValue) | UInt8(UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight.rawValue)))

        sv.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height * 2);
        return sv
    }()

    var textView: UITextView = {
        var tv = UITextView()
        tv.textColor = .darkGray
        tv.backgroundColor = .black
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return tv
    }()

    func setupViews() {

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(scrollView)            
        scrollView.addSubview(textView)

        scrollView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-16-[v0]-16-|", views: textView)
        scrollView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-16-[v0]-16-|", views: textView)           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code;

```
    var textView: UITextView = {
    var tv = UITextView()
    tv.textColor = .darkGray
    tv.backgroundColor = .black
tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    return tv
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

You set scrollView contentSize explicit as frame in this variant you should not use auto layout constraints with subviews of scrollView. Try this:

```
func setupViews() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(textView)
    textView.frame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint(0, 0), size: scrollView.contentSize).insetBy(dx: 16, dy: 16)
}
```

Another variant is not to set the scrollView contentSize explicit as frame, and make your scrollView subViews constraints to edges of scrollView and set this subViews height and width with constraints, scrollView will get content size from that width and height constraints. Example:

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height - 32).isActive = true
```

dont forget to set scrollViews and its subviews

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```